# SQL Server 2008 - Combine SUM queries from different tables into 1 result set

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to run some reports on the database (SQL Sever 2008) for our Incident Management System.
There are 2 tables, one containing Incident data and one containing Task data

The Incident table might look like this

```
Ref#  OpenDate  Category          Group  State
111   1/4/15    IncidentRequest   A      Open
112   1/4/15    ServiceRequest    A      Open
113   2/4/15    SalesRequest      A      Closed
114   3/4/15    IncidentRequest   B      Open
```

The Task table might look like this

```
TaskRef#  OpenDate  Group  State
211       1/4/15    A      Open
212       1/4/15    A      Open
213       4/4/15    B      Closed
214       5/4/15    A      Closed
```

I would like to run a query that would return
OpenDate, SUM(IncidentRequest), SUM(ServiceRequest), SUM(SalesRequest), COUNT(Tasks) for Group A
so basically the amount of all Incidents, Service Requests, Sales Requests and Tasks for each OpenDate where the Group is A

Ideally I would also like to minimise load on the SQL server, speed is not a huge priority

I have looked at JOINS, UNIONS etc but I am very new to SQL and find myself suffering from a bit of information overload.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
DT

Comment: Hello and welcome. What I think you want to do is do a pivotting on those 3 (incident, service, sales) value. Have a look here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.100).aspx are those Categories deterministic ? If they aren't - then you'll need dynamic sql.

Comment: You can try the `case ` with `group by ` and `count` instead of `sum`. and filter with the `where` clause on group should give you what you need.

Comment: That PIVOT link is fascinating, cheers. I may need to get some sleep before I can actually understand it though :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `Full Join` and conditional sums:

```
Select * From
(
  Select Date,
         Sum(Case When Category = 'Incident Request' Then 1 End) As ir,
         Sum(Case When Category = 'Service Request' Then 1 End) As ser,
         Sum(Case When Category = 'Sales Request' Then 1 End) As sar
  From Incidents
  Where Group = 'A'
  Group By Date
)i
Full Join
(
  Select Date, 
         Count(*) As rc 
  From Tasks
  Where Group = 'A'
  Group By Date
)t On i.Date = t.Date
```

Comment: That seems to work great! Thank you so much to Giorgi and all who contributed